# How can set value of type Text node for Attribute of html elements

Tags: javascript, html, textnode

according to [Text element document in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) Value of [Attr Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr) Can be of type **Text** element.

> The Text interface represents the textual content of Element or Attr.

But how can i set value of a DOM element attribute to **Text** object.
Some things like this:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('myId')
elm.attributes['class'] = new Text('app-class')
```

In web api documents, `value` of **Attr** is string.

### UPDATE:

I know attribute can be set by assigning string literal.But i want to set value with `Text` node datatype instead of `string` datatype

Answer (score 1):

You can update your element class via

```
document.getElementById("myId").className = "app-class";
```

Comment: The `class` attribute in sample code of question isn't important. I know attributes can be set by assigning string literal. But i want to set value with 'Text node' datatype instead of 'string' datatype